# Webhook for Kik Api?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, kik

> 'webhook': 'https://example.com/incoming',

How do I set a webhook for a kik api? There  is a confusion in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a server running, with a route that will accept the message from the bot.

Checkout https://github.com/kikinteractive/kik-node#your-first-echo-bot for an example